# How to use Spring Pageable object in controller without using Java Data?

Tags: spring, pagination, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I would like to ues `Pageable` object in controller's method to eliminate the redundant `page` and `size` parameters. Just like the following:

```
@RequestMapping("/list")
public String list(Model model , Pageable pageable) {
    logger.info("pageable = {}" , pageable);
    // ... skipped
}
```

Instead of:

```
@RequestMapping("/list")
public String list(Model model , Integer page, Integer size) {
    logger.info("page = {}, size = {}" , page, size);
    // ... skipped
}
```

However, after adding the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency to my `pom.xml`, I've been always asked for setting up the `'entityManagerFactory'` bean, which looks like something from the embedded hibernate dependency.

How can I use the `Pageable` obejct and get rid of the Spring Data things?

Answer (score 5):

`Pageable` is part of the [Spring Data Commons](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) project -
 and I've never seen it used outside of Spring Data.

That said... it may be possible, but you'd have to pull in the appropriate jar containing the `Pageable` class, without pulling in any of the Spring   Boot Starter Data - * dependencies. If you add the starter, Spring boot is going to attempt to perform automatic datasource configuration, which it sounds like you do not want.

You *could* try to pull in the single dependency that contains that class (`org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons` i believe). You should then have access to the `Pageable` class without any autoconfiguration.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use spring data JDBC. This would help you avoid the need to use JPA!

Here is a good source of information about jdbc: [Github-Spring Data JDBC generic DAO implementation](https://github.com/jirutka/spring-data-jdbc-repository)